# Nightclub flyer dataset

Tags: data-request, music

I am looking for a dataset containing images of nightclub flyers, if possible with:

- name and location of the club
- date of the event
- type of music
- type of event (e.g. student party, clubbing)
- a short description of the event

Examples of images of nightclub flyers:

[image]